# How to Get Windows boot again

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, uefi

I formatted the drive that contained Ubuntu Budgie from windows. Then I opened CMD with administrator privileges and head to diskpart and removed the Ubuntu directory from there, but maybe accidentally I also removed the boot directory and also tried to remove the Microsoft directory which gave an error or Denied. But I guess the boot directory was affected.

After a reboot I was unable to boot to windows. When I am starting my computer my motherboard is doing some kinda scan and entering the bios.
If I am heading to boot from disk, it is entering Grub rescue mode.

Then I installed Garuda Linux successfully from a flash drive, which I thought should overwrite the Grub, but maybe it didn't. Again after reboot when I am starting the computer, Grub rescue mode is appearing.

Then I connected a Windows iso flash drive and head over repair mode, opened up cmd and run the command
Bootrec.exe /FixMbr

Which also didn't gave any single change to the result
Then also tried
Bootrec.exe /FixBoot

Again no improvement on result.
Windows automatic repair systems are also failed.
The only thing I am able to do is seeing the entire disk from a Garuda Linux flash drive...

Can anyone help ???

Comment: Well I found the solution by myself, I reinstalled the Ubuntu in a new partition and that overwrote the Grub, resulting now I can access the Grub boot loader and can boot to Windows or Garuda or Ubuntu anywhere

Comment: A fresh install solves many issues.